# F# - POCO Class

Tags: f#, poco, ef-code-first

Hey there! I'm trying to write a POCO class in proper F#... But something is wrong..

The C# code that I want to "translate" to proper F# is:

```
public class MyTest
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The closest I can come to the above code in F# is something like:

```
type Mytest() =

    let mutable _id : int = 0;
    let mutable _name : string = null;

    [<KeyAttribute>]
    member x.ID
        with public get() : int = _id
        and  public set(value) = _id <- value

    member x.Name 
        with public get() : string = _name
        and  public set value = _name <- value
```

However when I try to access the properties of the F# version it just returns a compile error saying

*"Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."*

The code thats trying to get the property is a part of my Repository (I'm using EF Code First).

```
module Databasethings =

    let GetEntries =
        let ctx = new SevenContext()
        let mydbset = ctx.Set<MyTest>()
        let entries = mydbset.Select(fun item -> item.Name).ToList() // This line comes up with a compile error at "item.Name" (the compile error is written above)
        entries
```

What the hell is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, you can leave the word "Attribute" off of your attributes in F#, just like you can in C#. For example, `[<Key>]`

Comment: Also FYI - your F# `MyType` definition formatting got messed up when you copied and pasted and won't compile as is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class definition is fine, it's your LINQ that has a problem. The `Select` method is expecting an argument of type `Expression<Func<MyTest,T>>` but you're passing it a value of type `FSharpFunc<MyTest,T>` - or something similar to that anyway.

The point is you can't use F# lambda expressions directly with LINQ. You need to write your expression as an [F# Quotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) and then use the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) to run the code against an `IQueryable<>` data source. Don Syme has a [good overview of how this works](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/10/23/a-quick-refresh-on-query-support-in-the-f-power-pack.aspx).